# Inherit handles properties

Tags: matlab, plot

I have created an `axes` in a figure and I am defining its properties (`'Title'`, `'XLim'`, ...). Now I am creating a second `axes` and I want it to inherit the properties of the first one. Something like:

```
handles_axes2 = handles_axes1;
```

Afterwards it has to be possible to define different properties for any of them.

Is it possible to do that?

What I tried so far:

1) [`copyobj`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html) is copying the object but assigning to it different handles

2) I wonder if there is a possibility to `set` all the handles and not just some properties. It could also be nice to be able to select which handles not to assing:

```
handles_axes2 = set(handles_axes2, get(handles_axes2,"except(Color)")
```

Any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: I think the `copyobj ` is actually what you might want. Of course it will assign different handles, since the two objects, albeit identical in properties, are different instances. That means, after copying, modifying the original will not influence the copy, and the other way around too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @CST-Link, `copyobj` would do the job.

```
fig = figure;
handles_axes1 = axes('Parent',fig);
handles_axes2 = copyobj(handles_axes1,fig);
```